# Avoid rerendering when doing button.click() inside useeffect()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to set the data from child component to parent component's state in turn that data will be assigned to input text field. And then I want to automatically click the button to submit the data from input text field to `handleBtnSubmit()` function.

But when I did this child component is rendering indefinitely. Can someone please help resolving this kind of situation?

Parent

```
const [responses, setResponses] = useState([]);
const [currentMessage, setCurrentMessage] = useState('');

const submitAction = () => {
  setResponses((responses) => [...responses, message]);
  handleMessageSubmit(message.text);
  setCurrentMessage('');
};

const handleBtnSubmit = () => {
  submitAction();
};
       
<Messages
  messages={responses}
  parentData={{ currentMessage, setCurrentMessage, btnRef, handleBtnSubmit }}
/>
      
<div className='typing-area'>
  <div className='input-field'>
    <input
      type='text'
      placeholder='Type something here'
      required
      value={currentMessage}
      onChange={handleMessageChange}
      onKeyDown={handleSubmit}
    />
  </div>
  <button onClick={handleBtnSubmit} ref={btnRef}>
    <img src={sendButton} alt='Send Button' />
  </button>
</div>
```

Child

```
const setMessage = (option) => {
  parentData.setCurrentMessage(option);
  // parentData.btnRef.current.click();
  // console.log(parentData.currentMessage);
};

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(setCurrentMessage.currentMessage);
  // parentData.btnRef.current.click(); //tried this
  // parentData.handleBtnSubmit(); //also also tried directly calling handleBtnSubmit();
  //both are causing indefinite rerender
}, [parentData.currentMessage]); //tried this too
            
<li className='option' key={i} onClick={() => setMessage(option)}>
  {option}
</li>
```

Comment: It's unclear what component is rendered by what other component. What is the child component relative to the parent component? Can you edit your post to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

First, pass `currentMessage` as a separate property, instead of passing it within an object. Something like:

```
<Messages
    messages={responses}
    currentMessage={currentMessage}
    parentData={{ setCurrentMessage, btnRef, handleBtnSubmit }}
/>;
```

Then try passing the `currentMessage` prop as a dependency into the `useEffect` as shown below:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(currentMessage);
  setCurrentMessage.btnRef.current.click();
}, [currentMessage]); // child's message state
```

This way, the `useEffect` code is called only when the `currentMessage` changes, and not indefinitely.

Comment: The state is actually in parent component. I'm passing `state` and `setState` etc from parent to child as props.. Already tried giving `parentData.currentMessage` as dependency to `useEffect()`.. still didn't work.

Comment: @Sanjay I've updated the answer based on the info you shared. Hope it helps

Comment: Aneesh, thanks for a quick response. Looks like still something is missing. This time `useEffect()` is not getting executed second time onwards so the `click()` is not working. While debugging saw that `currentMessage` that I'm passing from parent to child as prop is `undefined`. Let me try some different approach and see again.

Comment: Sure np, once you're able to get the value to pass in, do share if it works or not

Comment: Hello Guys, This has been resolved. I created another state that stores the full value onclick/submit. And used that value as a dependency to the `useEffect()`. We can close this discussion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create another state that stores the full value onclick/submit. And use that value as a dependency to the `useEffect()`

```js
  const [messageText, setMessageText] = useState('');



  useEffect(() => {
    submitBtnRef.current.click();
  }, [messageText]);
```